# How do I collapse outlines in OneNote app?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I understand OneNote for desktop can collapse/expand outlines to any levels. However, I failed to find this feature in OneNote Android app (version 15.0.2727.2300). Did I miss it?

Comment: I suspect the answer is no. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost one year later and version 15.0.3232.1047 and this critical function is still missing - unless someone can explain how to this?

So I would say the answer is no